# Uncountably Categorical Theories and Embeddings

Tags: logic, model-theory

Suppose that $T$ is uncountably categorical. By the Baldwin-Lachlan Theorem, we note that $I(T,\aleph_0)=1$ or $\aleph_0$.

Suppose that $I(T,\aleph_0)=\aleph_0$. Is it always the case that we get the nice embedding property that we see with models of $(\mathbb{N};s)$? Namely, there exists a prime model and the $non-prime$ models are linearly ordered by elementary embeddings? i.e. (1) there exists a $\mathfrak{A}$ such that $|\mathfrak{A}|=\aleph_0$ and for all $\mathfrak{B}$, $|\mathfrak{B}|=\aleph_0$, we have $\mathfrak{A} \prec \mathfrak{B}$. (2) There exists a linear order $X$ on the countable models such that for $\mathfrak{B}_i,\mathfrak{B}_j$, if $i < j$, then $\mathfrak{B}_i \prec \mathfrak{B}_j$?

Thanks

Comment: It is basically true. For the details see the section 6.3 of Tent and Ziegler "A course in model theory".

Comment: @LevonHaykazyan: Awesome, thanks so much!